# Is any elementary extension of a weakly small structure again weakly small?

Tags: model-theory

Recently, I've been reading a paper in which the author makes use of the following definition apparently first introduced by Oleg V. Belegradek:

A structure $\mathcal{M}$ in a language $\mathcal{L}$ is called *weakly small*, if it has only countably many 1-types over every finite set $A$ of parameters.

My question is whether there is an example for a weakly small structure $\mathcal{M}$ which posesses an elementary extension $\mathcal{M} \prec \mathcal{N}$ that is not weakly small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a combinatorial example.

The language is $L = \{P_n\mid n\in \omega\}\cup \{R_n\mid n\in \omega\}$, where each $P_n$ is a unary relation symbol and each $R_n$ is a binary relation symbol.

Consider the universal theory $T$ asserting for all $n$:

- $P_{n+1}\subseteq P_n$
- $R_n\subseteq P_n\times P_n$ (so if $R_n(x,y)$, then $P_n(x)$ and $P_n(y)$).
- $R_n$ is a graph relation (symmetric and anti-reflexive).

Take the model companion $T^*$ of $T$. For any $k\in \omega$, writing $L_k = \{P_n\mid n<k\}\cup \{R_n\mid n<k\}$, the class of finite models of $T|_{L_k}$ is a Fraïssé class $\mathcal{C}_k$. If $M_k$ is the Fraïssé limit of $\mathcal{C}_k$, then $T^*$ is the union $\bigcup_{k\in \omega}\mathrm{Th}(M_k)$. It follows that $T^*$ has quantifier elimination, since any formula is an $L_k$-formula for some $k$, and $\mathrm{Th}(M_k)$ has quantifier elimination.

By QE, $T^*$ has countably many $1$-types over $\varnothing$: $\{p_n\mid n\in \omega\}\cup \{p_\infty\}$. Each type $p_n$ is axiomatized by $\{P_k(x)\mid k < n\}\cup \{\lnot P_k(x)\mid k\geq n\}$. So $p_\infty$ contains $P_n(x)$ for all $n$. The type $p_\infty(x)$ containing $P_n(x)$ for all $n$ is non-isolated, so there is a countable model $M\models T^*$ omitting $p_\infty(x)$. I claim that $M$ is weakly small.

Let $A\subseteq M$ be finite, say $A = \{a_1,\dots,a_k\}$. Since none of the $a_i$ realize $p_\infty$, we can choose $N$ least such that $\lnot P_N(a_i)$ for all $i$. By QE, a $1$-type $q(x)$ over $A$ is determined by:

- Which of the countably many $1$-types over $\varnothing$ $q$ extends.
- Which of the formulas $R_n(x,a_i)$ are contained in $q$.

But no formula $R_n(x,a_i)$ is contained in $q$ for $n\geq N$. Hence there are only finitely many (at most $(2^k)^N$) $1$-types extending each of the countably many $1$-types over $\varnothing$. So $M$ is weakly small.

Now let $M\preceq M'$ be an elementary extension such that $M'$ contains $a$ realizing $p_\infty$. Then there are continuum-many $1$-types over $\{a\}$, since for all $X\subseteq \omega$, the type $$q_X(x) = \{P_n(x)\mid n\in \omega\}\cup \{R_n(x,a)\mid n\in X\}\cup \{\lnot R_n(x,a)\mid n\notin X\}$$ is consistent, and if $X\neq X'$, $q_X$ and $q_{X'}$ are contradictory. So $M'$ is not weakly small.

---

By the way, recall that a theory $T$ is *small* if for all $n\in \omega$, there are only countably many $n$-types over $\varnothing$ consistent with $T$.

For a weakly small structure $M$ with $T = \mathrm{Th}(M)$, the following are equivalent:

1. Every elementary extension of $M$ is weakly small.
2. Every model of $T$ is weakly small.
3. $T$ is a small theory.

*Proof:* $2\implies 1$ is trivial.

$3\implies 2$: Suppose $N\models T$ and $A\subseteq N$ is finite. Enumerate $A$ as $\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}$. Now there is an injective map $S_1(A)\to S_{k+1}(\varnothing)$ given by $p(x)\mapsto \mathrm{tp}(a_1,\dots,a_k,b)$, where $b$ is any realization of $p(x)$. This map is injective, so if $T$ is small, then $|S_1(A)|\leq |S_{k+1}(\varnothing)|\leq \aleph_0$. Thus $N$ is weakly small.

$1 \implies 3$: Let's show by induction on $n\geq 1$ that $|S_n(\varnothing)|\leq \aleph_0$. In the base case, $|S_1(\varnothing)|\leq \aleph_0$ since $M$ is weakly small. Now assume $|S_n(\varnothing)|\leq \aleph_0$. There is a surjective map $S_{n+1}(\varnothing)\to S_n(\varnothing)$ which restricts each $(n+1)$-type to its first $n$ variables. Since $|S_n(\varnothing)|\leq \aleph_0$, it suffices to show that each fiber of this map is countable, i.e., for each $p\in S_n(\varnothing)$, $p$ has only countably many extensions to an $(n+1)$-type. Let $M\preceq M'$ be an elementary extension of $M$ containing a tuple $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ realizing $p$. Let $A = \{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$. Then there is a bijection between the $(n+1)$-types over $\varnothing$ extending $p$ and the $1$-types over $A$. But since $M'$ is weakly small, $|S_1(A)|\leq \aleph_0$. $\square$

Thus we see that the notion of weakly small fits nicely into a common pattern in model theory: it's a condition on formulas/types in $1$ variable in a structure $M$, and it has a stronger version (smallness) that means that it is true of all structures elementarily equivalent to $M$, i.e. it is really a property of $\mathrm{Th}(M)$.

For example:

- A strongly minimal theory is one whose models are all minimal.
- A strongly o-minimal theory is one whose models are all o-minimal (though it's a theorem that strongly o-minimal and o-minimal are equivalent).
- A strongly C-minimal theory is one whose models are all C-minimal.
  etc.

See some discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3662942/7062). The weakly small condition doesn't exactly have the same flavor as these notions of minimality, but it's still an instance of the pattern that if we have a strong condition in $1$ variable (few $1$-types over finite sets), then we can lift it to a conclusion in any number of variables (in a small theory, we have few $n$-types over $\varnothing$ for all $n$).